# ASP.NET ReportViewer controll excel export bad cell background

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, export-to-excel

I have a problem with the asp.net webforms reportviewer controll. When I export from this control to excel, the xls cells background colors goes wrong. All cells background color inherits the last cell background color.

The pdf and .doc export working well.

I'm using this exp. in the .rdlc file for coloring the cells: =IIF(Fields!State.Value = 0, "#FFFFFF", IIF(Fields!State.Value = 1, "#00FF00", IIF(Fields!State.Value = 2, "#FFFF00", IIF(Fields!State.Value = 3, "#FF0000", "#808080"))))

I hope somebody can help me.

Bye!

ps.: Sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `Switch` instead of `IFF`. Also, try giving the value in Color name like: `Red` instead of `#FF0000`

```
 =Switch(Fields!State.Value = 0, "#FFFFFF", 
Fields!State.Value = 1, "#00FF00", 
Fields!State.Value = 2, "#FFFF00", 
Fields!State.Value = 3, "#FF0000", 
"#808080")
```